# php mysql select statements for sort by filters not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

UPDATE!

I have been trying to test some sort by filters to add to my products pages in my lamp web app.

Working from the mysqli request I use to dynamically load all product subcategories in my store pages. However I want to add the sort by features for customer ease of use.

Page is loading like so:

[image]

I am not getting any parse errors.

Any help greatly appreciated. I am a beginner!

```
    <?php
 include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';
 include_once 'includes/functions.php';
 include_once 'includes/header.php';
 ?>
 <?php

if (isset($_GET['asc']))
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, subcategory, price FROM products_coaliment_via_laietana WHERE subcategory = 'Bread' ORDER BY price ASC");
else
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, subcategory, price FROM products_coaliment_via_laietana WHERE subcategory = 'Bread' ORDER BY price DESC");


if (!$result)
die("Failed to show queries from table");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
$products_item = '<div class="product-category-wrapper">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$products_item .= <<<EOT
                            <div class="custom-product-column">
                            <div class="product-wrapper">
                            <div class="product-image">
                                <img src="{$obj->product_img_name}" alt={$obj->product_name}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-price">
                                <p>{$currency}{$obj->price}</p>
                             </div>
                             <div class="product-title">
                                <h4>{$obj->product_name}</h4>
                                {$obj->product_desc}
                            </div>
                            <div class="basketControls">
                                    <ngcart-addtocart id="{$obj->id}" name="{$obj->product_name}" price="{$obj->price}" quantity="1" quantity-max="10">Add to Cart</ngcart-addtocart>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
EOT;
}

$products_item .= '</div>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>          

<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<button type="submit" id="asc" name="asc" value="asc">ASC</button>
<button type="submit" id="asc" name="desc" value="desc">DESC</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @rMX: Did you even look up that function?

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @AbraCadaver [See my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762131/php-mysql-select-statements-for-sort-by-filters-not-working#comment55292321_33762238) under the answer given. It's not about "name".

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you, sorry I realised I had copied an older version of the code. The original demo I had used was in mysql so I tried using mysqli.

Comment: now you made an edit and have syntax errors in attempt 2.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the heads up! I will take a closer look.

Comment: you're welcome. Your code is failing in more ways than one. For your mysql version: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. For your mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - You will see what's not happening and what the errors are.

Comment: `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Thanks again @Fred-ii- for the quick and comprehensive answer. I will read through the manuals on error reporting. I would like to add the the attempt 1 is actually running and echoing the products since I changed the column name 'typo', however the asc desc functions aren't. I will continue working on my mysqli version anyhow.

Comment: You have a syntax error message. It should also specify the file and line number where the error occurs. Go look at that line (and possibly the few lines immediately before it), and you should be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your `name` fieldname with backticks as "name" is a reserved word in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM products_nonstop24 ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

Comment: "name" is not a MySQL "reserved word", it's a "keyword" (2 different animals) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html - That isn't the problem here. Look over their code again and with a *"fine tooth comb"*. You'll see what's wrong. I've spotted 3 things. Edit: 4.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, was actually an oversight in making demo work for my schema. My column name is actually product_name , have made necessary edit. thanks again!